# 'az functionapp deployment' reports success, but Functions view in Azure is empty

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I have 1 function app that for some reason doesn't want to deploy (All 30 other function apps I manage deploy fine with the same ZipDeploy method).

After running the following AzureCLI command to deploy to an existing consumption based function app:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $functionAppName --src $artifactPath
```

This returns a successful deployment result (see bottom of question for the full JSON result), however looking in the Functions blade for the function app, this is empty:

[image: the functions blade in the portal (empty)]

My question is this - what am i doing wrong here? Why does deploying a function via AzureCLI fail?

A bit of background:

- Functions we're using are precompiled C#
- The function apps are created by Terraform
- This function is a service bus trigger function that has the same host.json/functions.json as other successful function deployments

Things i've tried so far:

- Deployed via the 'Publish' route in Visual Studio 2019 as a test. This works successfully.
- Running the AzureCLI command locally, same result
- Checked the function code structure against the [suggested folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#folder-structure), this complies
- Compared the zipped artifact i'm deploying against other successful deployment zips. Same structure as working functions.

Full logging from the AzureCLI command:
Setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to false
Waiting SCM site to be updated with the latest app settings
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202

Full JSON response from the AzureCLI command:

```json
active                : True
author                : N/A
author_email          : N/A
complete              : True
deployer              : ZipDeploy
end_time              : 23/09/2020 16:32:28
id                    : 02c6219516244615beca1c126749baa1
is_readonly           : True
is_temp               : False
last_success_end_time : 23/09/2020 16:32:28
log_url               : https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log
message               : Created via a push deployment
progress              :
provisioningState     :
received_time         : 23/09/2020 16:31:55
site_name             : xxxx
start_time            : 23/09/2020 16:31:55
status                : 4
status_text           :
url                   : https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest
```

EDIT 1: Here are the contents of the wwwroot folder for anyone interested - they follow the same structure as other functions we have (which deploy fine and display in the Functions view in the portal):
[image: The contents of the wwwroot folder]

Comment: Can you check in Kudu if the function is present or not?

Comment: You can go to 'https://<your-function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole' ->site->wwwroot to check what HarshitaSingh said. And check the function app name in your command.

Comment: Hey guys yes indeed the files are all there - i've added a screenshot to my original question to show the contents of the folder (no differences from other functions we have deployed successfuly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long last we found out the cause of why the function app didn't deploy.

Turns out it deployed fine (the files were deployed in the right place) - it's just that the function runtime crashed on startup.

We found the usage of 'builder.Services.AddMvc()' caused this issue:
[image]

Which makes sense, given Azure Functions aren't Mvc. Derp!

We removed this line and voila, no more issues.

Answer (score 1):

I might know what's wrong during your ZipDeploy process. Maybe the way you get your zip folder is wrong.

As I said, you can check if the destiny function app name is correct, and check if the content in *https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole*  -->**site**-->**wwwroot**(kudu) is correct.

**The correct step of ZipDepoly is:**

**1.** Click Publish option just like deployed via the 'Publish' route in Visual Studio 2019

**2.** Choose folder to create publish file.

[image]

**3.** Compress the publish file content you got from last step. The structure of publish file is same as in docs.

> ```
> Publish.zip
>  | - bin
>  | - host.json
>  | - FunctionName
>  | | - function.json
> ```

**4.** Publish that zip file by your command. And the content of wwwroot should be same as publish file:
[image]

Comment: @Jack S, please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Great suggestion! Sadly this didn't work - the Functions list is still empty in the portal. The wwwroot folder has got the files in (in the structure MS recommends), but these were there before anyway.

Comment: I am wondering why you have a `function_dataplat*.json ` file under the root directory, which is unfamiliar with mine. Did you create the publish folder the same way with me? Another suggestion is create a new function app and try again.

Comment: That's not something from our function app solution - that's something internal .NET Core uses i think. See here:
https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/#depsjson

Comment: It cannot make sense, cause my dependency manifest file was included in `bin` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help Doris Lv - i found the cause in the end (posted as the answer)