# Zip deploy of Azure function was a success but Functions in Azure is empty

Tags: azure-functions

Hi I have a Azure function timer which I am trying to deploy via ZIP deploy, it succeeds  but Functions in Azure is empty.

[image]

The cmd I am using for the deployment is
**az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $resourceGroupName -n $functionName --src $sourceZipPath**

The JSON response from the cmd is as below.

```
{  "active": false,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "ZipDeploy",
  "end_time": "2022-03-25T12:37:54.9247211Z",
  "id": "373e929429a14bee8b6368949e922789",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2022-03-25T12:37:54.9247211Z",
  "log_url": "https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "received_time": "2022-03-25T12:33:05.5662452Z",
  "site_name": "xxxx",
  "start_time": "2022-03-25T12:33:17.5130554Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
```

I can see all the files inside the file structure (screen shots below)
[image]
[image]

Not sure where I am going wrong. It works perfectly when deployed from Visual Studio 2019.

I did check on the post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032902/az-functionapp-deployment-reports-success-but-functions-view-in-azure-is-empt" and followed the steps but no luck.

Can anyone suggest what else can I try.

Comment: check with the log URL provided in the browser and provide us with the log data! The log URL response looks like https://i.imgur.com/8TEKLR9.png

Comment: Same message as your screen shot. `{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"No log found for 'latest'.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException","StackTrace":"   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\DeploymentManager.cs:line 98\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\DeploymentController.cs:line 376"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same issue while deploying the Azure Function using AZ CLI both from Local CLI and Azure CloudShell:**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g HariTestRG -n KrishNet6FuncApp --src "C:/Users/Hari/source/repos/DotNet6/TimerTrigger1205.zip"
```

[image]

[image]

As Per this [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/19954), I came to know that the command `az functionapp deployment source config-zip` having the issue with AZ CLI versions and tried by downgrading to 2.28 version of Azure CLI but not succeeded the desired result.

**`Command to downgrade the Azure CLI version:`**

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://azcliprod.blob.core.windows.net/msi/azure-cli-2.28.0.msi -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; rm .\AzureCLI.msi
```

**Alternative workaround to this zip push deploy of Function Apps is using PowerShell Commands and working well**.

### Updated Answer

After enabling the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` and deploying the Azure Function Zip using `AZ CLI`, it deployed successfully and shows the functions in the Azure Portal along with the files in the `wwwroot` folder.

[image]

**AZ CLI Command:**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g HariTestRG -n KrishNet6FuncApp --src "C:/Users/Hari/source/repos/DotNet6/TimerTrigger1205.zip"
```

[image]

From this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization), we came to know that some deployment customization has to be done before deploying the Function App as a Zip Push, i.e., by default the app setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` is false which enables the continuous integration deployment.

For the PowerShell Workaround, refer this [GitHub Page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-powershell).

Comment: Never tried this before, can you guide on how to deploy using PowerShell please.

Comment: This is resolved now, thanks @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt when I deploy it resets SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT back to false

Comment: Hello @amplifier, how about the functions in the portal, are functions are visible in the portal function app?

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt Hi, no, they don't. I set up a bitbucket pipeline. I have iothub trigger, timer trigger and kafka trigger. The only issue I have with kafka trigger. Its wwwroot is empty. For iothubtrigger and timertrigger deployment is ok. I can only deploy the kafka trigger via VS2022, but not via CI/CD

Comment: Hello @amplifier, looks like your scenario (deployment way) is different. Its from bitbucket pipeline so could you please raise a new question request with more details to assist with better & clean solution.

Comment: calling **az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g MyResourceGroup -n MyDevKafkaAzfunc --src ./af-my-azfunkafka.zip** from local powershell doesn't upload it as well, also it give a success output

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73052071/bitbucket-pipeline-zip-deploy-of-kafka-azure-function-is-successful-but-function