# #AuthorizationFailed az functionapp deployment source config-zip

Tags: azure, azure-functions, command-line-interface

I got this error message when I tried to upload the zip file using the fuctionapp deployment command. How can I grant access to the user? I am actually Admin of the resource group.

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g dt-rg -n dt-function-test --src ProcessHubToDTEvents.zip
```

> (AuthorizationFailed) The client 'XXX@YYYY.com' with object id
> 'fe90558f-8f13-4e0b-8812-50ac3987ebba' does not have authorization to
> perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/5649ad97-1fd3-460f-b569-9995bbb6c5c0/resourceGroups/dt-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/dt-function-test'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials. Code: AuthorizationFailed Message: The
> client 'XXX@YYYY.com' with object id
> 'fe90558f-8f13-4e0b-8812-50ac3987ebba' does not have authorization to
> perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/5649ad97-1fd3-460f-b569-9995bbb6c5c0/resourceGroups/dt-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/dt-function-test'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To perform any operations like Create, Update, Deploy or delete on the Function App-level tasks, **Contributor** role is enough for the user.

Refer to [one of my workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71617500) in Azure Function App deployment using Azure CLI command

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip ...
```

[image]

Also, to get more information what roles provides which permissions on Azure Functions App Level, refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#user-management-permissions) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Facing the exact same issue right now!