# Zip deploy of Kafka Azure function is successful but Functions in Azure is empty

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

I have 3 azure functions:

1. IotHub trigger
2. Timer trigger
3. Kafka trigger

I upload them via CI/CD of the bitbucket pipeline

But after uploading I only have IotHub trigger and Timer trigger working
The *wwwroot* folder of Kafka trigger is empty.
Bitbucket pipeline calls

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip
```

under the hood. I tried to call it locally for a created zip from the powershell - same result, empty folder, and no errors in the output.

Comment: Hello @amplifier, I'm not aware of bitbucket pipeline deployment, but tried over the Azure CLI command prompt using the command and got all the 3 triggers created locally as you can see here - https://i.imgur.com/lkninjE.png, https://i.imgur.com/uHUpf2R.png - all trigger folders contains `function.json` files.

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt Could you attach your kafka project please? And a zip file as well

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt How do you create zip file?

Comment: Hello @amplifier, In 2 ways I have zipped the Azure functions project and tried to deploying using the `az functionapp deployment` command after enabling the `scm_do_build_during_deployment` to `true`. Zipping is 1) through right click menu on project folder > Compress to Zip file 2) through powershell command as shown here - https://i.imgur.com/C6uwNGE.png

Comment: Hi harikrishnarajoli-mt SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT resets to false after deployment. How to prevent it?

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt do you publish the trigger before compression? I caompress the publish folder, so in my zip file I have folders: .azurefunctions, runtimes and dll's like Azure.Core etc

Comment: No @amplifier, I have published after compressing to zip format!

Comment: and you can get my local Azure Functions Project with triple triggers (IotHub, Kafka and Timer) in the Zip format as you asked - https://github.com/HariKrishnaRajoli-MT/KrishAzNetTripleTriggersBitBucketRepro.git

Comment: Hello @amplifier, any update on the issue?

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt Hello, yes, it works locally and on the bitbucket (switched to the atlassian pipline), thank you!

Comment: Hello @amplifier, could you please post the answer how you resolved the issue on the bitbucket cloud so that, it would help to other community members

Comment: @hari-krishna sure

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt Hi, just added one more answer in case you're interested in.

Comment: Where you have added it!

Comment: @HariKrishna moderator deleted it

Comment: I guess As Per SO Rules, you should not add more than 1 answer. If you want to add, you can update the existing answer with more information!

Answer (score 0):

In yml file replace

```
- pipe: microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.3
```

with

```
- pipe: atlassian/azure-functions-deploy:2.0.0
```

**Update (it fails again)**

It started to fail again. Now not only can't I deploy kafka triggers, bit ordinary iothub and timer one.

It neither work with atlassian nor microsoft pipeline (microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2)

It seems to me that it is something relating to deploy of triggers itself. Even deploying from VS2022 fails sometimes:

> Publish has encountered an error. The Publish URL
> https://mytriggerdevtimeraf.scm.azurewebsites.net/ is unreachable. The
> application may be stopped, restarting or unavailable. Try again once
> the publish target is available.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\USERNAMR\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA81B.tmp"

go to log:

> 8/31/2022 1:13:39 PM
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: The Publish
> URL https://mytriggerdevtimeraf.scm.azurewebsites.net/ is unreachable.
> The application may be stopped, restarting or unavailable. Try again
> once the publish target is available.    at
> Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Functions.Publish.ZipDeployPublishProfileConfiguration.d__10.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.PublishProfilesServiceImpl.ServerProjectProfilesManager.d__62.MoveNext()
>
> ===================

Stopping triggers before deployment doesn't help

I have 4 trigger and only one is deployed.
To detect error I go to the portal click trigger and see the error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
> 'D:\home\site\wwwroot./.azurefunctions/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.FunctionMetadataLoader.dll'.
> Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid