# Azure Function App Missing Function in Console UI After Publishing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, gitlab-ci, azure-cli, cicd

I'm programming automation to my CI/CD Gitlab to deploy my Azure Functions projects programmatically.

But I'm having an issue when I publish a new function to a function app created previously using az cli like the example below:

```
$ func azure functionapp publish $AZURE_APP_NAME ${SLOT_PARAMETER} ${FUNCTION_LANGUAGE} --nozip

$ az webapp config appsettings set -g $AZURE_RG_NAME -n $AZURE_APP_NAME ${SLOT_PARAMETER} --settings "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0"
```

The command line shows that the new function was built, created and deployed successfully. But when I check if the new function was created in my app using the Azure Console UI nothing was shown.

I even tried deploying the function as a zip package using the default `publish` command or like the example above using `--nozip` and setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0` to deploy files.

It's strange because I could see the deployed function for another app function using the same script. In this way the behavior of the console UI function app seems erratic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned by @pravallika-kothaveerannagari I needed to enable `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` during the deployment of my function to build it on the App Service.

Besides, I've changed the deployment of the function to `az functionapp deployment source config-zip`, and not using Azure Function core tools anymore.

```
echo '[config] SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true' > .deployment
zip -r build.zip MyFunction
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $AZURE_RG_NAME -n $AZURE_APP_NAME ${SLOT_PARAMETER} --src build.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing continuous deployments for the Azure Function App, you have to enable one of the configuration settings in the Azure Portal Function App > Configuration Menu i.e., `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`.

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name PravuFunctionApp \
--resource-group PraviRG \
--settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

After configuring this setting, then deploy using `az cli` command or function core tools command `func azure functionapp publish`, it will show the Functions in the Azure Portal Function App.

Refer to this SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71617500/16630138) regarding the similar issue i.e., No Functions showing after deployment/publishing.