# Azure Functions: deployment from Git does not work with .NET 7

Tags: azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, .net-7.0

I have configured Deployment from Azure DevOps Git for my Azure Functions project (runtime: dotnet-isolated). It executes successfully, but no functions are created/visible in Azure portal. When I compare it to the production slot (deployed from VS Code) in service editor I see different project structure, see screenshots.

Deployed from Git:

[image]

Deployed from VS Code:

[image]

Git deployment output:

[image]

Is this a bug of Azure or do I do something wrong? All logs look fine, what else can I check?

Comment: Not really an answer, but the path `app_data/jobs/continuous` created by the first example seems to mostly show up in topics discussing [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create), which AFAIK have some commonality with Azure Functions, but are not the same thing, so it looks as though the tool has misinterpreted what your code is and has tried to deploy it as a WebJob. I believe this menu option actually goes and creates pipeline artefacts in your DevOps tenant; if this is the case, could you show them?

Comment: Hi @TomW. I checked and actually it did not create neither new Pipeline nor Artifact in our DevOps

Answer (score 1):

> I have configured Deployment from Azure DevOps Git for my Azure Functions project (runtime: dotnet-isolated). It executes successfully, but no functions are created/visible in the Azure portal.

- For Continuous Deployments of Azure Function App using GitHub Actions, you have to enable the setting ***'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT'*** to ***true*** in the Application Configuration.
- One of my previous workarounds #[74593738](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593738/azure-function-app-missing-function-in-console-ui-after-publishing) solved the similar issue that the user is not able to see the functions deployed with CI/CD using Gitlabs and resolved by enabling the above setting.
- You can enable that setting in many ways such as Azure Portal, CLI, Or as you're using the GitHub Actions then you may have [action.yml](https://github.com/Azure/functions-action/blob/master/action.yml) file where you can add that setting and enable it to be true.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same result with this setting

Comment: Worked for me by adding SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true via the Portal! Thanks!!!