# Azure Function App - Swap deployment Slots stuck then crashing completely

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

Recently my function apps have stopped swapping slots, they worked fine for months but suddenly they have all stopped swapping by taking a long time then crashing. I have recreated the function apps using the same scripts and have replicated the issue but still can't fix.

Is there anything I am setting to stop the slots from switching?

Here is the fundamental build script I am using. I am able to run this but when trying to swap slots in Azure it freezes then crashes with a vague error message:

```
 # Azure Login
az login

# Set deployment Environment
$environment = "stage"

# Resource Group Variables
$subscriptionId = ""
$domain = "test4"
$resourceGroup = "xx-platform-$domain-$environment"
$region = "northEurope"

# Functions app variables
$storageName = "xxfn$domain$environment" # must be less than 24 chars and all lower case
$functionAppDeploymentSlotName = "test"
$functionAppName = "xx-platform-$domain-fn-$environment"
$functionAppEnvironment = "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT=Development"
$websiteRunFromPackage = "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1"

#########################################################################################################################################################################
## Resource Group
Write-output "Creating resource group";

# Set subscription
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

# Create resource group
az group create -l $region -n $resourceGroup  

#########################################################################################################################################################################
## Functions App
Write-output "Creating Functions App";

# Create storage account
az storage account create --name $storageName --location $region --resource-group $resourceGroup --sku Standard_LRS

# Create functions app - using consumption plan
az functionapp create --name $functionAppName --storage-account $storageName --consumption-plan-location northEurope --resource-group $resourceGroup --functions-version 4

# Set functions app configuration settings

# Environment
az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings $functionAppEnvironment 
# WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE 
az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings $websiteRunFromPackage 
# SET DOT NET FRAMEWORK ERSION
az functionapp config set --net-framework-version v6.0 -g $resourceGroup -n $functionAppName


# Create functions app deployment slot
az functionapp deployment slot create --name $functionAppName  --resource-group  $resourceGroup --slot $functionAppDeploymentSlotName
```

Comment: Are you swapping the slots using the CLI Cmdlets or in Portal and What is that vague error message you have received?

Comment: I found the issue. Azure had issues with swapping slots and decided not to inform anyone. Eventually they did, the issues were in several regions.

Comment: Oh, it might be Azure Service Outage issue in some regions.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script in initializing the variable values directly to the cmdlets:

```
# Azure Login
az login
az account set --subscription "<Ur_Azure_Subscription_Id>"

# Function App Create
az functionapp create --name dt-platform-fn-stage --storage-account dtfnstageenvironment --consumption-plan-location northEurope --resource-group HariTestRG --runtime dotnet --functions-version 4

# Environment
az functionapp config appsettings set --name dt-platform-fn-stage --resource-group HariTestRG --settings AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT=Development

# WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE
az functionapp config appsettings set --name dt-platform-fn-stage --resource-group HariTestRG --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1

# SET DOT NET FRAMEWORK ERSION
az functionapp config set --net-framework-version v6.0 -g HariTestRG -n dt-platform-fn-stage

# Create functions app deployment slot

az functionapp deployment slot create --name dt-platform-fn-stage --resource-group HariTestRG --slot test
```

[image]

Created the Http Trigger Function using the cmdlets given in the below given MS Document.

For Continuous deployments, this app setting needs to be configured:

```bash
az functionapp config appsettings set --name dt-platform-fn-stage --resource-group HariTestRG --settings "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true"
```

Deployed the Function to the Azure Functions using `az cli` cmdlet given in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645818) of my workarounds.

By default, Auto Swap on Slots will be disabled:
[image]

It is working fine during the slot swapping and make sure you have followed the considerations mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#automate-slot-management) that also provides the list of **`az cli`** cmdlets for managing the slots like creating, listing, deleting, swapping and auto swapping configuration.

Above Azure CLI Commands have been taken from this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=azure-cli,in-process) references.