# Azure function published to app from cli not listed under functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-python-sdk

I've the following directory structure for an Azure function app:

```
    .
    |-test
    |-TriggerTrainingApp
        -host.json
    |---azure_ws
    |---test_func
        -__init__.py
        -function.json
        -requirements.json
        -local.settings.json
```

I created a function app using the following command from inside `TriggerTrainingApp` directory using the cmd:

`az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location eastus --runtime python --runtime-version 3.9 --functions-version 4 --name <APP_NAME> --os-type linux --storage-account <STORAGE_ACCOUNT> --resource-group <resource_group>`

It was created as expected --verified on ui.
Then I tried to publish the function by cd into `test_func` and running the cmd:

`func azure functionapp publish TriggerTrainingApp`

The logs say the command ran succesfully but when I run `func azure functionapp list-functions TriggerTrainingApp`, it doesn't list any functions. The output is simply:

`Functions in TriggerTrainingApp:`

The files inside `test_func` are now available under the function app`s app files on the ui. What am I doing wrong? How do I push these files to a new function under TriggerTrainingApp?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
az functionapp config appsettings set --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --settings "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true"
```

- You have to add this setting to the *Azure Function App Configuration Menu* before publishing any functions to it.
- After updating the above config setting, publish the functions and you’ll be able to see the functions.

On my research, I found a similar [issue-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645818/16630138) given by @*HariKrishna* such as Functions are empty after deploying the Azure Function Project using command line, but the above config setting is updated using the portal in the above-mentioned solution.
This can also be achievable using `az cli` cmdlets that I have mentioned above which will help to fix your issue.

Comment: Actually this was a version issue. Downgrading core-tools to 3.x fixed it.

Comment: Tried to add this appsettings for v4, didn't work