# Can't see C# Azure Function when deployed on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When deploying my C# Azure Function from VSCode onto Azure, I can't seem to see it on the Portal.
I've also noticed that the message "No HTTP Triggers" appears specifically for C# related functions, because I've attempted deploying my Python function using Azure Function extension and it worked as expected.

The same happens when I use the AZ CLI.

Here are a few logs that appear when VS Code deploys the function:

```
14:57:32 functionapp: Processed 496 files...
14:57:52 functionapp: Processed 719 files...
14:58:00 functionapp: Finished successfully.
14:58:01 functionapp: Running post deployment command(s)...
14:58:01 functionapp: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
14:58:01 functionapp: Deployment successful.
14:58:15 functionapp: Syncing triggers...
14:58:25 functionapp: Querying triggers...
14:58:26 functionapp: No HTTP triggers found.
```

When using the AZ CLI:

```
> az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g rg-name -n functionapp --src publish_output.zip
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
    "active": true,
    "author": "N/A",
    "author_email": "N/A",
    "complete": true,
    "deployer": "ZipDeploy",
    "end_time": "2023-03-29T13:11:34.0203343Z",
    "is_readonly": true,
    "is_temp": false,
    "last_success_end_time": "2023-03-29T13:11:34.0203343Z",
    "log_url": "https://functionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
    "message": "Created via a push deployment",
    "progress": "",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "received_time": "2023-03-29T13:10:35.008044Z",
    "site_name": "functionapp",
    "start_time": "2023-03-29T13:10:35.8988656Z",
    "status": 4,
    "status_text": "",
    "url": "https://functionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
  }
```

Does somebody know where this issue could be coming from?

TIA!

**EDIT: Some snippets**

So, I do some dependency injection in my Function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(A.Startup))]

namespace A
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHelper, Helper>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<
                SomeInterface,
                SomeClass
            >();
        }
    }
}
```

I modified my class constructor and I do use a decorator

```
namespace A
{
    public class FunctionApp
    {
        private IHelper _helper;
        private SomeInterface _someInterface;

        public FunctionApp(
            IHelper helper,
            SomeInterface someInterface
        )
        {
            _helper = helper;
            _someInterface = someInterface;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The function's entry point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="req"></param>
        /// <param name="log"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [FunctionName("FunctionApp")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log
        )
        // The code starts here
```

Comment: For your function, have you added `decorator` like [FunctionName("MyFunc")] ? show us some of your code snippet.

Comment: Your build should generate a function.json file for your Function, which describes the function's trigger for the Functions runtime, and your publish should copy that file into your Azure app folder. Is all this working correctly?

Comment: @Fares, In your Function App Portal Configuration > Application Settings > Add this setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to true and then try deploying your functions project.

Comment: So it's normal to not be able to see the code for C#, unlike Python? Because when checking in "Code + Test" i can only see the function.json

Comment: You cannot see the code if deployed from zip package. If it is the C# Script code (created from portal), then you can see and edit the code from the Azure Function App Code+Test Menu.

Comment: Have you checked by adding the application setting I have given in 1st comemnt and then deploying the functions?

Comment: Yes, I've tested your method and it worked. Just wanted to confirm whether viewing the code was possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't see C# Azure Function when deployed on Azure

As I have shown in my previous SO User's Issue #[71617500](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645818), the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` should be added for continuous deployment of Azure Functions.

[image]

> confirm whether viewing the code was possible or not

- If you deploy the Function Project using Zip Package, then you can edit only the configuration files `function.json` and `host.json` through App Service Editor or Kudu SCM Site.
- If and only if you create the functions (.csx format) in the Azure Portal Function App, you can edit the function code using **Code+Test** Menu or **App Service editor**

[image]

**App Service Editor**:

[image]

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#platform-features) for more information on platform features like in-portal editing Azure Function Code.