# Deploy existing python FastAPI project on azure functions

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, fastapi

I'm trying to deploy an existing fast api app on azure functions using VSCode.

I get this error:

```
No HTTP triggers found
```

My project structure:

[image]

And this is the content of function.json

```
{
    "scriptFile": "backend/main.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
          "get",
          "post"
        ],
        "route": "{*route}"
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "$return"
      }
    ]
}
```

Main.py file , i have added the azure function handler.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from apis.base import api_router
from core.config import settings

from db.base import Base
from db.session import engine
from db.utils import check_db_connected
from db.utils import check_db_disconnected
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from webapps.base import api_router as web_app_router


def include_router(app):
    app.include_router(api_router)
    app.include_router(web_app_router)


def configure_static(app):
    app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


def create_tables():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


def start_application():
    app = FastAPI(title=settings.PROJECT_NAME, version=settings.PROJECT_VERSION)
    include_router(app)
    configure_static(app)
    create_tables()
    return app


app = start_application()


async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    await check_db_connected()
    try:
        body = await req.get_body()
        return func.HttpResponse(str(body))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('Error')
        return func.HttpResponse("Error", status_code=500)

    await check_db_disconnected()
```

Is there something i missed in here?

I tried deploying a dummy api and it was success. Changed directory structure in my project and still im unable to deploy it to azure functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No HTTP triggers found`

As the user @*HariKrishna* shown in this issue #[75877908]([Can’t see C# Azure Function when deployed on Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877908/cant-see-c-sharp-azure-function-when-deployed-on-azure/75898779#75898779)) for the above error, one application setting should be added to get the functions in the Azure Function App in the Continuous deployment scenario for any language runtime.

That Application setting is:

```json
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: true
```

[image]

And We cannot change the default folder structure for the Azure Functions project as it is fixed as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#folder-structure) and temporary solution as shown in this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024448/change-the-default-folder-structure-in-azure-function-project-with-python) by the same user.