# Functions list in Azure Portal and CLI empty

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have faced problem with function app. I have two separate environments and deployed code base to both of them. The functions are triggered by service bus. Both function apps working as expected when they are triggered. However in one environment I observer problem that Function list in azure portal and when called from CLI is empty. (App Service Plan with S1 tier is used) So far I have tried all the options I have found:

- Setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 1 or removing
- Setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 1 or removing
- Files in kudu and function.json visible
- Storage account access works
- Tried setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true
- Tried to deploy default project from Visual Studio directly Can you assist what I may check also to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are working with the continuous deployments or deploying in multiple environments, enable one of the configuration settings using Azure CLI with below command.

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name <functionapp> --resource-group <ResourceGroup> --settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

Once enabled, redeploying the function app with the functions using AZ CLI commands or function core tools will display the entire list of functions.

*You can also refer this* [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617500/zip-deploy-of-azure-function-was-a-success-but-functions-in-azure-is-empty) *by @Hari Krishna for relevant issue.*

[image]

2. Check the logs by going to the `log stream` under `Monitoring`. It might help in identifying why it is failing.

[image]

You can also access these logs using the storage account that is synced with the function app by navigating to
`File shares -> < Function > -> Browse -> Log files -> Functions` as shown below:

[image]

3. Check the runtime version of the functions and update it if necessary. By going into `configuration` within the `function app` blade, ensure that the `"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION"` app setting is set to the proper version.
4. `Deployment -> Deployment slots`

   Verify the deployment slots to make sure that it is deployed correctly in the appropriate environment.

After a successful deployment, I tried to trigger the service bus queue in my environment, and it worked as meant.

[image]

Note: *You can also look into the user's required permissions for deployment and grant them if anything is needed.*